# writing data to columns in excel with openpyxl after

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Back again...
So now, I've been able to get my data pulled into python with openpyxl and have the calculations completed, but now I'm stuck on how to get it printed back out to another sheet.
The below only prints the last gross value to the referenced cell, which obviously is not what I would like my outcome to be.
I need the row increased and the gross values printed to the excel file.
in B2, B3, etc...
Referencing the "gross" back with the name of the individual, which is in my dictionaries, and printing that to the third sheet would be even better, so names in A1:Ax and gross B1:Bx. 
Help getting to either would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test_book.xlsx") 
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hours')   
employee_names=[]
employee_hours=[]
for row in sheet['A']:
    employee_names.append(row.value)
for row in sheet['B']:
    employee_hours.append(row.value)
print(employee_names)
print(employee_hours)
my_dict=dict(zip(employee_names,employee_hours))
print(my_dict)

sheet2=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Rate')
employee_names2=[]
employee_Rate=[]

for row in sheet2['A']:
    employee_names2.append(row.value)
for row in sheet2['B']:
    employee_Rate.append(row.value)
print(employee_names2)
print(employee_Rate)

my_dict2=dict(zip(employee_names2,employee_Rate))
print(my_dict2)

sheet3=wb.get_sheet_by_name('payable')
#pulls key from dictionary, multiples it by other number
for row in sheet['A']:
    if row.value in my_dict:
        gross=(float(my_dict[row.value]*float(my_dict2[row.value])))       
        print(format(gross,'.2f'))
        sheet3.cell(row=2,column=2).value=gross

wb.save("Test_book.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think this really should be done in Excel itself, using a function like vlookup. Either way, all you really need to do is keep track of what row you are on

```
...
sheet3=wb.get_sheet_by_name('payable')
#pulls key from dictionary, multiples it by other number
rownum = 2
for row in sheet['A']:
    if row.value in my_dict:
        gross=(float(my_dict[row.value]*float(my_dict2[row.value])))       
        print(format(gross,'.2f'))
        #put name in A
        sheet3.cell(row=rownum,column=1).value=row.value
        #put gross pay in B
        sheet3.cell(row=rownum,column=2).value=gross
        rownum += 1

wb.save("Test_book.xlsx")
```

Additionally, openpyxl supports array-index style cell referencing, which can make things easier to read/write:

```
#these are equivalent
sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = value
sheet.['A1'] = value
```

You may also at some point find the function openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter() useful.